# What's the meaning of "READY=2/2" output by command "kubectl get pod $yourpod"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

```
kubectl get pod run-sh-1816639685-xejyk 
NAME                      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
run-sh-1816639685-xejyk   2/2       Running   0          26m
```

What's the meaning of "READY=2/2"? The same with "1/1"?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The "Ready" column shows how many containers in a pod are considered ready.

You can have some containers starting faster then others or having their readiness checks not yet fulfilled (or still in initial delay). In such cases there will be fewer containers ready in the pod than the total number (e.g. 1/2) hence the whole pod will not be considered ready.

Comment: flawless answer!

Comment: Thanks for this. Interestingly K8s official reference doesn't have any description or explanation of the output. Seems they expect it to be intuitive. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#get